# If search not found how do i return it?

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't know if this is dumb to ask. But i am can't figure it out. I have the following query:

```
 include 'db.php';
  if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['searchQuery'])){
      $name = $_POST['searchQuery'];
      //-query  the database table
      $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE  name LIKE '%" . $name . "%'";
      $result=mysqli_query($db, $sql);

}
```

This finds the matches from the form input so later i use `mysqli_fetch_array()` and show the results after looping it. But i can't figure out if the string entered by users do not match in the table, how do i show them that what he is searching can't be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you sanitize the variable `$name` using [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

To check to see if no results are found, you want to use [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) and check to see if it's zero or not.

**Example**

```
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['searchQuery'])){
   $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['searchQuery']);

   $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE  name LIKE '%{$name}%'";
   $result=mysqli_query($db, $sql);
   if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
      // Success and Results
   }else{
      // Failed OR No Results
   }
}
```

**Why Use mysqli_real_escape_string**

It's important to use `mysql_real_escape_string` otherwise any user can perform an SQL Injection. An SQL Injection is when a user can modify the SQL query to leak or delete information.

Comment: Instead of using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` you should advise the use of "prepared statements" to prevent sql injection vulnerability and query syntax issues.

Comment: @arkascha I thought PDO and mysqli are both considered to be safe to use when coded properly.

Comment: I did not deny that, did I? But prepared statements have a number of advantages over single, manual escaping of arguments. In general it is considered to be a cleaner and more efficient approach.